# Why does malloc rely on mmap starting from a certain threshold?

Tags: linux, performance, memory-management, malloc

I was reading a little bit about `malloc` and found the following in the `malloc`'s man page:

> Normally, malloc() allocates memory from the heap, and adjusts the
> size of the heap as required, using sbrk(2).  When allocating blocks
> of memory larger than MMAP_THRESHOLD bytes, the glibc malloc()
> implementation allocates the memory as a private anonymous mapping
> using mmap(2).  MMAP_THRESHOLD is 128 kB by default, but is
> adjustable using mallopt(3).  Allocations performed using mmap(2) are
> unaffected by the RLIMIT_DATA resource limit (see getrlimit(2)).

So basically starting from the threshold MMAP_THRESHOLD malloc start using `mmap`.

1. Is there any reason to switch to `mmap` for large chunks?
2. Could this hit the process execution performance?
3. Does the `mmap` system call force a context switch?

Comment: (1) Yes; (2) theoretically yes, but in practice this improves performance in most cases, which is the reason for (1); (3) every system call does.

Comment: @n.m. Not all the system calls require a context switch. Take a look to the the following thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238326/system-call-and-context-switch

Comment: Apparently it's a difference in terminology. You probably want to know if mmap is blocking or not. The call itself may not be blocking but it hardly matters. Your process will get a page fault and be forced into a context switch anyway.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

(1) Pages acquired via anonymous `mmap` can be released via `munmap`, which is what glibc is doing. So for small allocations, `free` returns memory to your process's heap (but retains them in the process's memory); for large allocations, `free` returns memory to the system as a whole.

(2) Pages acquired via anonymous `mmap` are not actually allocated until you access them the first time. At that point, the kernel has to zero them to avoid leaking information between processes. So, yes, the pages acquired by `mmap` are slower to access the first time than those recycled through your process's heap. Whether you will notice the difference depends on your application.

The cost of not using `mmap` is that freed memory is still tied up by your process and unavailable to other processes on the system. So this is ultimately a trade-off.

(3) It does not "force" a context switch and is, I believe, unlikely to cause one. `mmap` does not actually allocate the pages; it just manipulates the page map for your process. That should typically be a non-blocking operation. (Although I admit I am not 100% sure about this.)

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'm still investigating on the point #3 just to see if the mmap force a context switch or not.

Comment: @rkachach Do you have any update on the finding? I am also trying to learn whether mmap systemcall results in context switch

Comment: @talekeDskobeDa There's no guarantee that it will, and there's no guarantee that it won't, either.  You mustn't rely on either behavior.