# Does mmap force a context switch in Linux

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management

This is related to another question I have already asked: [Why does malloc rely on mmap starting from a certain threshold?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33128587/why-does-malloc-rely-on-mmap-starting-from-a-certain-threshold)

I got an answer for most points but we are not sure about if an mmap forces a context switch or not specially for the anonymous case (in the case of file mapping I assume that the process loses that CPU since loading the file from the disk is a time consuming operation)

So my doubts are:

1. Does the process lose the CPU when mapping an anonymous page?
2. Is there a simple way in Linux to check if the process loses the CPU after a specific system call?

Comment: Calling mmap doesn't load the file from disk.  It just arranges for the file to be loaded on-demand when you access certain memory addresses.

Comment: @Wyzard thanks for the clarification. So the process lose the CPU or not in this case?