# Linux huge pages doesn't work with malloc

Tags: c, linux, memory

I have Linux THP enabled for all processes:

```
cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
[always] madvise never
echo 1024 | tee /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages
```

But seems that my example code which allocetes and uses more than 100Mb (supposedly over 50 2MB huge pages) doesn't use huge pages at all and uses regular pages:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define SIZE 1024*1024*100

int main(void)
{
        char *buf = malloc(SIZE);
        memset(buf, 'A', SIZE);
        for (;;) {
                printf("%p\n", buf);
                sleep(1);
        }
}
```

Before and after starting this example I see the static picture wtih `grep HugePages_ /proc/meminfo`:

```
HugePages_Total:    1024
HugePages_Free:     1023
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
```

But `free` shows that over +100Mb are used while example is running.

What is the reason of Linux THP not working?

Comment: This is likely relevant: [**Why does malloc rely on mmap starting from a certain threshold?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33128587/why-does-malloc-rely-on-mmap-starting-from-a-certain-threshold)

Comment: Is your application linked with libhugetlbfs?

Comment: @stark Nope, and I'm sure it shouldn't. Typical DPDK application that perfectly uses huge pages, has no references to this library just like all DPDK rte_* libraries...

Comment: @stark He's using THP so he doesnt have to link to libhugetlbfs

Comment: did you grep `grep AnonHugePages /proc/meminfo `  thats where the kernel docs say they should be showing up.   The values you show are for explicit HugePages from the lib.

Comment: @UpAndAdam Great!!! Indeed `AnonHugePages`  changes... Can you explain and sketch out it as answer?

Comment: @NK-cell done thanks for confirming that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the documentation you will discover that the command you performed is not checking THP huge pages usage but instead explicit Huge Tables ( which originates from libhugetlbfs )

To find the usage of THP Huge pages you should instead perform the following:
`grep AnonHugePages /proc/meminfo`

taken from https://access.redhat.com/solutions/46111